# For loop not giving expected output in bash

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I have created a script to find multiple strings from a file. But getting a long output which is not required.
And wanted to get following output.
For example: If all strings are matched echo `All nodes are UP` else `WEB1 WEB2 down`
In case if WEB1 and WEB2 are not found in that file.

Below is my script alongwith output:

```
arr=("WEB1" "WEB2" "WEB3" "WEB4" "WEB5" "WEB6" "WEB7" "WEB8" "WEB9" "WEB10" "pro-webs3")

for i in ${arr[@]}
do
  if grep -w "$i" Filename >> /dev/null
then
echo $i >> /dev/null
echo "node are up"
else
echo "$i Node is down"
fi
done
```

Output:

```
WEB1 Node is down
All nodes are up
All nodes are up
All nodes are up
All nodes are up
All nodes are up
All nodes are up
All nodes are up
All nodes are up
All nodes are up
pro-webs3 Node is down
```

Comment: Indentation is super helpful - please use it...

Comment: That script wouldn't produce the claimed output, because you call `exit` whether or not `grep` succeeds. The loop (and the script) terminate in the first iteration.

Comment: True for indentation. But this script is NOT giving the shown output, it actually exit on the first match, either up or down (and node name for up won't show either).

Comment: I edited the question, It was mistakenly added.

Comment: If you post a sample of Filename we can help you do this the right way (which will NOT be a shell loop - see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an array of failed nodes and act accordingly: list down nodes if not empty.

```
arr=("WEB1" "WEB2" "WEB3" "WEB4" "WEB5" "WEB6" "WEB7" "WEB8" "WEB9" "WEB10" "pro-webs3")
failed=()

for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
  if ! grep -q -w "$i" Filename
  then
    failed+=("$i")
  fi
done

if [ "${#failed[@]}" -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "All nodes are UP"
else
    echo "${failed[@]} DOWN"
fi
```